# Decode/Unescape Unicode Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, decode, unescapestring

I am new to decoding hence I am unable to decode below response while using UrlFetchApp.

Below is the function I am using to fetch data but getting values in unicode which I need to decode. Any function that I can use to decode this?

```
function scrape() {
  
  var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skillselect/invitation-rounds");
  var elements =/id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PageSchemaHiddenField_Input" (.*?)\/>/gim;
  
  var x = url.getContentText().match(elements);
  
  Logger.log(x);
  
}
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is the best way, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function scrape() {
  var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skillselect/invitation-rounds");
  var elements =/id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PageSchemaHiddenField_Input" (.*?)\/>/gim;
  var x = url.getContentText().match(elements);

  var res = unescape(x[0].replace(/\\u/g, "%u")); // Added

  Logger.log(res)
}
```

#### Result:

When above modified script is used, as a sample, the values are converted as follows.

From:

```
\u003cp\u003eThe table below shows the number of invitations issued in the SkillSelect invitation round on 11 September 2018.\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003ch3\u003eInvitations issued on 11 September 2018\u003c/h3\u003e\n\n
```

To:

```
<p>The table below shows the number of invitations issued in the SkillSelect invitation round on 11 September 2018.</p>\n\n<h3>Invitations issued on 11 September 2018</h3>\n\n
```

#### References:

- [unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrape() {
  var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skillselect/invitation-rounds");
  var elements =/id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PageSchemaHiddenField_Input" (.*?)\/>/gim;
  var x = url.getContentText().match(elements);

  var res = unescape(x[0].replace(/\\u/g, "%u")); // Added

  Logger.log(res)
}
```